# on setState render a new component

Tags: react-component, spfx

I have an analog clock
using

https://github.com/zackargyle/react-analog-clock

I have a textbox that fetches city name and timezone on autocomplete,

- Default clock2 loaded with offset +8
- On select of city in textbox
- Fetch City Name
- Fetch Timezone
- Re-render the clock2

How can I code that?

```
 public render(): React.ReactElement<Props> {
    return (
 <div className={styles.time}>
            <AnalogClock theme={Themes.light} width={120} gmtOffset=${this.state.gmtoffset} /><br/>
            {this.state.wxLoc}

 </div>
);
```

I attempted

```
this.showClock2(this.state.gmtoffset);
////////////////////////

private showClock2(offset="+8"){
  let show=`<AnalogClock theme={Themes.light} width={120} gmtOffset=${offset} /><br/>
  {this.state.wxLoc}`;
  return show;

}
//other codes

public render(): React.ReactElement<Props> {
    return (
 <div className={styles.time}>
            {this.showClock2()}

 </div>
);
```

it shows Literal Code, Is it possible to Render the `<AnalogClock/>` ?

Comment: I think you would benefit from reading this semi-official beginners tutorial about react https://www.taniarascia.com/getting-started-with-react/

Comment: I want to re-render AnalogClock when there is update from timezone. The data for timezone was "+0800" and the AnalogClock accepts gmtoffset as "+8" thus need to re-format.

Comment: Thanks, page 1 works
private showClock2(offset="+8") {
 
 ReactDOM.render(<AnalogClock theme={Themes.light} width={120} gmtOffset={offset} />, document.getElementById('root'))


}

Answer (score -1):

```
private showClock2(offset="+8") {

 ReactDOM.render(<AnalogClock theme={Themes.light} width={120} gmtOffset={offset} />, document.getElementById('root'))


}
```

Add  in the public render and it works